# A function with $R_0(f)=\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, holomorphic-functions

I'm looking for a function $f$ that satisfies the following:
$$R_0(f) = \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}$$
and $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$.
I was thinking about something like $$\frac{e^z}{log(z)}$$
but it doesn't work. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: What is $R_0(f) $, the residuum of $f$ at $0$ ? If yes, then take $ \frac{c}{z}$ with $c=  \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}$.

Comment: Yes it is the residue of $f$, to show this we can apply the residue theorem for rational functions, can't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)= \frac cz$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$ and $R_0(f)=c$. Hence , with $c=  \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}$, the function $f$ has the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Your series is a Bessel function value...
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!} = I_1(2)
$$
where $I_1(x)$ is the  [**modified Bessel Function of the first kind**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), a solution of the differential equation
$$
x^2 y'' + xy' + (x^2-1)y = 0
$$
with Taylor series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+1}
$$